# How to network hundreds of sensors over a serial connection?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, communication, high-speed

So I'm looking for a way to connect hundreds (300-400) sensors (like an accelerometer) together over a serial connection to a micro-controller. The sensors would transmit about 500kbps each.

I've been looking at I2C, SPI, and CAN, but none would have the speed requirements to deal with the large number of devices.

The other idea I had was to split up the devices. For example, I would connect every 10 to a controller via I2C, then have the controller communicate over a faster communication standard such as USB3.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 500K * 400 = 200Mbps.  so that is doable.  but difficult to manage on a single link.  you will probably want to spread them out in groups of 10 or so as you mentioned.  and then combine those, and then combine those...

Comment: if they could handle that rate, you could use a uart, tx of one goes to the rx of the other, in a big ring.  everyone has a tag and a slot to put their data in, as they move data around the ring they add the latest value for their sensor, the ring of data spins forever.  but everyone would have to communicate at 200Mbps,  which is likely not doable for a microcontroller.

Comment: @dwelch What standard would you recommend to use for the sensors as well as the final connection which would be 200Mbps.

Comment: Are they all transmitting continuously or do they operate in bursts?

Comment: @Tom They have a bit of memory and can be operated in bursts.

Comment: you are quickly going to overload microcontrollers.  one microcontroller for 10 devices is 5Mbps.  how fast of a microcontroller are you using?  one in the ones or tens of mhz?  625Kbytes a second for one microcontroller.   no doubt you cant be processing this through each microcontroller, just store and forward in hardware buffers.  but as it combines to a larger and larger pipe, you quickly exceed the clock rate of the mcu yes?  microcontrollers dont sound like the right solution.  usb or ethernet perhaps with something with more horsepower, but you still need hundreds of

Comment: individual sensor connections.

Comment: maybe an array of cplds feeding a fatter pipe feeding a processor

Comment: duh, did this for half my career, or worked with folks that did, should have thought of this first.  This kind of thing is very typical for pcm telemetry (IRIG 106).   A set of fpgas.  One combines and sends the data out, others multiplex groups of inputs to the ADCs, and feed the combiner at the right time.  COTS equipment available on both the encoder and ground station side if you want to simply buy the stuff..

Comment: If each sensor can send all it's data in 1/127th of some arbitrary 'cycle time' then you could get away with I2C as you can have 127 on a single bus I believe (assuming your sensors actually have that many address slots but there are I2C bus multiplexers for that anyway. Each sensor would be transmitting for some fraction of the total 'on' time, that way the number of buses you need is (No. of sensors)/(Max number of IDs)*(time spent transmitting)/(time spent not transmitting + time spent transmitting)

Comment: @Tom 127 devices would be 0.5Mbps * 127 = 63.5Mbps which is a lot more then the max of 3.2Mbps I2C can support.

Comment: @dwelch Micro-controller was probably a bad term to use. At the end, I want it to go to a computer which will have enough processing power to handle the 200Mbps data. I just need to figure out how to take so many sensors and combine them into 1 pipe that gets to the computer.

Comment: gigabit ethernet certainly works.

Comment: @Mahdi not if each is only transmitting for 1/127th the time, that's the only way it'd work over I2C

Comment: @Tom Even if transmitting at 1/127th of the time, it still needs to transmit at an average of 63.5Mbps. It just means that multiple bits are being sent while connected to each sensor.

Comment: @Mahdi yeah, you're right, I'd forgot to account for the total data rate, I was thinking 500kbps for 1 time slot out of 127, so I should assume 500kbps is the average data rate from these things, not just the connection speed. In that case, you may have to go with something like ethernet as dwelch suggested or you may be able to get away with a couple of RS485 links, I'm not sure RS485 has any real limitations on bandwidth other than signal integrity and transceiver bandwidth and it'd be a bit simpler to implement than ethernet.